# why sometime, push remote notification use parse not work

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I see same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993499/pushes-sent-sometimes-are-1-and-sometimes-are-0

but it does not have a answer.

Sometime, i use parse web send notification, but my device does not receive notification. I see if "Pushes Sent" is 0 then my device does not receive remote notification. But if "Pushes Sent" is 1, my device receives remote notification.

I send the notifications to all device, not filtered, and the deviceToken is registered. Why sometime is "Pushes Sent" 0?

See image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/62aTF.png